# How to enable webix from Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webix

In my Node application, I want one of the html files under views to show a simple webix message.

My app.js is just having usual stuff as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var bks = require('./routes/shelf'); 
var bprsr = require('body-parser');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', require('hogan-express'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.use('/', bks);
app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and the html file under views folder have a client side js file sourced into it as below which is under public folder.

Inside the public folder, I have the entire webix codebase and codemirror copied from the below links:

https://github.com/webix-hub/tracker/tree/master/codebase 
https://github.com/webix-hub/components

I have also done npm install webix from the command prompt inside my node application folder.

However, still if I try to write below code in the client.js as below:

```
webix.ready(function() {
   webix.message("hello world");

});
```

I get the error on browser console:

> client.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: webix is not defined
>       at client.js:1

What I am doing wrong in using webix to use it from my Node application?

Comment: There are three possibilities. Either the script file that exposes webix object is not downloaded or the script file is not exporting webix to global namespace or you are accessing webix object before the script file that exposes webix is downloaded and parsed.

Comment: @Jebin could you please tell me where from I can download that script file and how can I exporr the same to global namespace. Thanks

Comment: Can we see your html code where you are including webix.js and client.js? Also check in your browser console at the network tab whether the webix.js file is downloaded or not.

Comment: @Jebin Thanks, I included this line in my html code <script type="text/javascript" src ="/plugins/webix/codebase/webix.js"></script> , after that it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Webix is a set of UI widgets. It doesn't really make sense to "Use Webix from [a] Node application". Your Node application shouldn't be concerned with serving the static files that make up Webix.

Th easiest way to use Webix is to [load it from the CDN](https://blog.webix.com/use-webix-cdn-for-fast-web-apps/), and create REST ([or GraphQL](https://docs.webix.com/desktop__server_graphql.html) - see this [demo](https://snippet.webix.com/om5pqfnl)) API endpoints in your Node application that supply data, which you then load in Webix components such as [Datatable](https://docs.webix.com/datatable__index.html).